# R: predict new values for groups

Tags: r, predict, tidyverse

I've calculated a different regression for each group in a data frame:

```
DF.L <- DF %>%
group_by(Channel) %>%
do(Fit = rlm(L ~ -1 + Y + I(Y^2), data = .))
```

I want to apply this set of regressions to another data frame. To do so, I'm testing how to apply it to the same data frame:

```
DF %>%
group_by(Channel) %>%
do({
    Lfit <- predict(subset(DF.L, Channel == unique(.$Channel))$Fit, .)
    data.frame(., Lfit)
})
glimpse(DF)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
Calls: %>% ... do_.grouped_df -> eval -> eval -> predict -> predict
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the built-in `ChickWeight` data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


head(ChickWeight)
```

> ```
>   weight Time Chick Diet
> 1     42    0     1    1
> 2     51    2     1    1
> 3     59    4     1    1
> 4     64    6     1    1
> 5     76    8     1    1
> 6     93   10     1    1
> ```

---

### Fit some models

```
ChickWeight_models <- ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Diet) %>% 
  do(fit = MASS::rlm(weight ~ Time + I(Time^2), data = .))

ChickWeight_models
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
> Groups: <by row>
>
> # A tibble: 4 x 2
>     Diet       fit
> * <fctr>    <list>
> 1      1 <S3: rlm>
> 2      2 <S3: rlm>
> 3      3 <S3: rlm>
> 4      4 <S3: rlm>
> ```

So I've created a very similar object to your **DF.L**. It's a frame with the four groups, each with an `rlm` object in a list-column called **fit**.

---

### Make up some test data

Now I'll make up some data to test this model on. In this case, I'll just take the original data and add some noise to each of the variables.

```
ChickWeight_simulated <- ChickWeight %>% 
  mutate(Time = Time + runif(length(Time)),
         weight = weight + rnorm(length(weight)))

ChickWeight_simulated
```

> ```
>     weight       Time Chick Diet
> 1 42.72075  0.9786272     1    1
> 2 51.12669  2.8399631     1    1
> 3 58.64632  4.4576380     1    1
> 4 63.77617  6.1083591     1    1
> 5 75.40434  8.1051792     1    1
> 6 91.75830 10.7899030     1    1
> ```

Now we want to combine the dataframe of the models with the new data to test on. First we `group_by` and `tidyr::nest` the simulated data. This creates an object that is a dataframe with the four groups and a list-column called **data**, each element of which contains a rolled-up dataframe.

```
ChickWeight_simulated %>% group_by(Diet) %>% nest()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 2
>     Diet               data
>   <fctr>             <list>
> 1      1 <tibble [220 x 3]>
> 2      2 <tibble [120 x 3]>
> 3      3 <tibble [120 x 3]>
> 4      4 <tibble [118 x 3]>
> ```

---

### Add the original models to the new data

Then we can join it to the models dataframe:

```
ChickWeight_simulated %>% group_by(Diet) %>% nest() %>% 
  full_join(ChickWeight_models)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>     Diet               data       fit
>   <fctr>             <list>    <list>
> 1      1 <tibble [220 x 3]> <S3: rlm>
> 2      2 <tibble [120 x 3]> <S3: rlm>
> 3      3 <tibble [120 x 3]> <S3: rlm>
> 4      4 <tibble [118 x 3]> <S3: rlm>
> ```

Now we group by **Diet** again, and use `broom::augment` to make a prediction of each model on the new simulated data. Since each group is one row, there is one element each of **fit** and **data**; we have to extract that single element out of each list-column into a usable form by using `[[1]]`.

```
ChickWeight_simulated_predicted <-
ChickWeight_simulated %>% group_by(Diet) %>% nest() %>% 
  full_join(ChickWeight_models) %>% 
  group_by(Diet) %>% 
  do(augment(.$fit[[1]], newdata = .$data[[1]])) 

head(ChickWeight_simulated_predicted)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 6
> # Groups:   Diet [1]
>     Diet   weight       Time Chick  .fitted  .se.fit
>   <fctr>    <dbl>      <dbl> <ord>    <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1      1 42.72075  0.9786272     1 43.62963 2.368838
> 2      1 51.12669  2.8399631     1 51.80855 1.758385
> 3      1 58.64632  4.4576380     1 59.67606 1.534051
> 4      1 63.77617  6.1083591     1 68.43218 1.534152
> 5      1 75.40434  8.1051792     1 80.00678 1.647612
> 6      1 91.75830 10.7899030     1 97.26450 1.726331
> ```

---

### Sanity check

To prove that this really only used the model from a particular level of **Diet** on the simulated data from that level of **Diet**, we can visualize the model fit.

```
ChickWeight_simulated_predicted %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, weight)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(Time, 
                  ymin = .fitted-1.96*.se.fit, 
                  ymax = .fitted+1.96*.se.fit),
              alpha = 0.5, fill = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(Time, .fitted), size = 1, color = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~Diet)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! But IMHO the tidyverse should make it easier @hadley.

Answer (score 3):

I think your error comes from how you are calling predict. I can't fix your exact code, but here is a simple way you can get predictions from your model. A more sophisticated way using `purrr` and `nest` is outlined here: http://ijlyttle.github.io/isugg_purrr/presentation.html#(1)

**UPDATE - the `purrr` and `nest` way**

Just adding this to show that it can be done pretty easily within the `tidyverse`, using `predict`. See link above for more details.

```
library(tidyverse)

# shuffle the rows to mix up the species
set.seed(1234)
myiris <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), replace = F),]

# create first dataset - use the first 50 rows for running the model
iris_nested <- 
    myiris[1:50,] %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    rename(myorigdata = data)

# create second dataset - use the other 100 rows for making predictions
new_iris_nested <- 
    myiris[51:150,] %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    rename(mynewdata = data)

# make a model function
my_rlm <- function(df) {
    MASS::rlm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = df)
}

# get the predictions (see the GitHub link above which breaks this into steps)
predictions_tall <- 
    iris_nested %>% 
    mutate(my_model = map(myorigdata, my_rlm)) %>% 
    full_join(new_iris_nested, by = "Species") %>% 
    mutate(my_new_pred = map2(my_model, mynewdata, predict)) %>% 
    select(Species, mynewdata, my_new_pred) %>% 
    unnest(mynewdata, my_new_pred) %>% 
    rename(modeled = my_new_pred, measured = Sepal.Length) %>%
    gather("Type", "Sepal.Length", modeled, measured)
```

The nested `predictions_tall` object looks like this:

```
predictions_tall %>% nest(-Species, -type) %>% as.tibble()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     Species     type                  data
      <fctr>    <chr>                <list>
1     setosa  modeled <data.frame [32 x 4]>
2 versicolor  modeled <data.frame [33 x 4]>
3  virginica  modeled <data.frame [35 x 4]>
4     setosa measured <data.frame [32 x 4]>
5 versicolor measured <data.frame [33 x 4]>
6  virginica measured <data.frame [35 x 4]>
```

And finally, the plot to show the prediction results:

```
predictions_tall %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Species, linetype = Type))
```

[image: species_plot]

**ORIGINAL - the `broom` way**

*I've updated this now to only calculate predictions for each group using the model for that group.*

This way uses the `broom` package - specifically the `augment` function - to add fitted values.  See more here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Since you don't supply data, I use `iris` here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# first shuffle around the rows of iris
set.seed(1234)
myiris <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), replace = F),]

# first data - first 25 rows for running the models on
origiris <- 
    myiris[1:25,] %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    rename(origdata = data)

# second data - last 50 rows for predicting on
prediris <- 
    myiris[101:150,] %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>% 
    rename(preddata = data)


# estimate models on the first 25 rows
# a separate model is estimated for each species
iris_mod <- 
    origiris %>% 
    mutate(mod = map(origdata, ~ MASS::rlm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = .)))
```

First get fitted values for the original dataset (not essential, just for illustration):

```
# get fitted values for the first dataset (origdata)
origiris_aug <-  
    iris_mod %>% 
    mutate(origpred = map(mod, augment)) %>% 
    unnest(origpred) %>% 
    as.tibble()
```

The `origiris_aug` predictions dataframe looks like this:

```
origiris_aug
# A tibble: 25 x 10
   Species .rownames Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width  .fitted   .se.fit      .resid
    <fctr>     <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1  setosa        18          5.1          1.4         0.3 5.002797 0.1514850  0.09720290
 2  setosa         2          4.9          1.4         0.2 4.931824 0.1166911 -0.03182417
 3  setosa        34          5.5          1.4         0.2 4.931824 0.1166911  0.56817583
 4  setosa        40          5.1          1.5         0.2 4.981975 0.1095883  0.11802526
 5  setosa        39          4.4          1.3         0.2 4.881674 0.1422123 -0.48167359
 6  setosa        36          5.0          1.2         0.2 4.831523 0.1784156  0.16847698
 7  setosa        25          4.8          1.9         0.2 5.182577 0.2357614 -0.38257703
 8  setosa        31          4.8          1.6         0.2 5.032125 0.1241074 -0.23212531
 9  setosa        42          4.5          1.3         0.3 4.952647 0.1760223 -0.45264653
10  setosa        21          5.4          1.7         0.2 5.082276 0.1542594  0.31772411
# ... with 15 more rows, and 2 more variables: .hat <dbl>, .sigma <dbl>
```

And now what you actually want - making predictions on the new dataset:

```
# get fitted values for the second dataset (preddata)
# each model is fitted to the appropriate species' nested dataframe

prediris_aug <- 
    iris_mod %>% 
    inner_join(prediris, by = "Species") %>% 
    map2_df(.x = iris_mod$mod, .y = prediris$preddata, .f = ~augment(.x, newdata = .y)) %>% 
    as.tibble()
```

The `prediris_aug` dataframe looks like this:

```
prediris_aug
# A tibble: 50 x 7
   .rownames Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  .fitted  .se.fit
       <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 8.557908 3.570269
 2       115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4 8.348800 3.666631
 3       117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8 8.123565 3.005888
 4       139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8 7.772511 2.812748
 5       103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 8.537086 3.475224
 6       107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 7.551086 2.611123
 7       119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 9.180537 4.000412
 8       135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4 7.889823 2.611457
 9       124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8 7.822661 2.838502
10       118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 9.009263 3.825613
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Nice @meenaparam, but there should be only one prediction for each row, according to the Species value of the row.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist Using `group_by` before the `do` means we fit a model for each level of species, so we end up having three models to predict with. In your data, do you only want to make predictions for new observations based on the model built on the same grouping value?

Comment: Yes. In my case, it doesn't have sense to use a model from another Channel.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist No problem, didn't realise this. You have an answer now, but I'll update this one now to show the `purrr` way, which I think makes it even easier.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very interesting option.